# File not creating when using writeFile in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

Following is my code in update method for an event -

```
Event.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, updateData, function(err, event){
  if (err) {
    res.send({"message": "Something went wrong!", "err": err, "status_code": "500"});
  }
  else {
    console.log("----I AM IN ELSE STATEMENT----");
    // WRITE DATA TO LOG FILE 
    fs.writeFile("/logs/update-event.txt", event, function(err) {
      if(err) throw err;
        res.send({"message": "success", "data": event, "status_code": "200"});
    });
  }
});
```

And following is the error I am getting when updating -

```
/home/myproject/controllers/events.js:71
          if(err) throw err;
                        ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/logs/update-event.txt'
```

Though If  am using the following code, **it is creating File** at the root of the folder-

```
fs.writeFile("update-event.txt", event, function(err) {
```

I tried by manually creating `logs` named folder but no luck.

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: That obviously means, `/logs/` directory is not existing: `ENOENT` = Error No Entry.

Comment: @AxelAmthor I tried by creating a logs directory but still the same error

Comment: wrong path for the logs directory. `/logs` is located in the root of the filesystem, not your application. Otherwise use `logs/update-event.txt` w/o the leading `/ `

Comment: @AxelAmthor Thx a ton..please post this as an answer and I will accept it as it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That obviously means, `/logs/` directory is not existing: `ENOENT` = Error No Entry.

And probably wrong path for the logs directory. `/logs` is located in the root of the filesystem, not your application. Otherwise use `logs/update-event.txt` w/o the leading `/`